# Accessing Model Variable in a block in a controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I must be missing something really obvious here but i cant see wood for trees at the moment, and this feels a lot like a noob question! :)

I have a model HousePrice, with two attributes, postcodes and price.

The postcodes are currently a string including some of the address at the beginning and then 1 or more postcodes. For example..

```
postcodes = "High Street, Tetsworth, Thame, OX9 OX9 7AB OX9 7AD OX9 7AE OX9 7AS OX9 7AT        OX9 7BS OX9 7BZ"
```

I have a ruby script that strips the text i dont want and returns only the postcodes as an Array. It may not be the best, but it does the job!

I have a custom def in my HousePrices controller and it is called from a link on the index page. However, i keep getting

```
undefined method `slice!' for nil:NilClass
```

and i am confused!

Here is what i am trying it with...

```
def second_distance_run

HousePrice.all.each do |pca|
    @postc = []
    @array = pca.split(',').to_a
    @srt = @array[3]
    @srt.slice!(0,5)
    aa = @srt.split(' ').to_a
    aa.each_slice(2)    do |elem|
      @postc << (elem[0].to_s) + (elem[1].to_s)  
    end
 end
```

In consol it works if you give it the string, but not if it gets it from the database. I know i am missing somthing silly but i am struggling!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: well, `logger.info pca` would tell you what you actually have. Most likely you get an empty string or a string with less than 4 parts after the split.

Comment: btw: the `.to_a` after the split is useless, since `split` returns an array anyway.

Comment: How are you calling `split` on `pca`? It should be an instance of `HousePrice` model, not a string - do you define split on the model (or do you delegate it somewhere)? Most likely you want `pca.postcodes.split...` instead

Comment: @BroiSatse... I did have that in before, must have removed by accident. But even with 'array = pca.postcodes.split(',')' still same error.

Comment: @thorsten müller...Cant figure how to run that, getting undefined method! Sorry, still a beginner with Rails!

Comment: Just verify if @srt is not nil before calling slice!

Comment: `logger.info` should work in the controller, if it's in some library you must use `Rails.logger.info` instead.

Comment: Try to use puts an object and then exit and check the code line by line u will defiantly go the problem.

Comment: Stop teaching the man to use loggers for such matters. Use debuggers!

Comment: Run `puts HousePrice.pluck(:postcodes).select{|p| p.count(',') < 3}` in your console. If it prints anything it will be the value which is causing the issue.

Comment: @BroiSatse...`puts HousePrice.pluck(:postcodes).select{|p| p.count(',') < 3}` returns all the elements from the database as expected. Calling `HousePrice.last` and then running my code works fine! So what am i missing with the iteration?

Comment: Inquisition should stop following witches, and catch the ones who use `logs` and `puts` for debugging in such manner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's look closer to the code. The error happens here:

```
@array = pca.split(',').to_a
@srt = @array[3]
@srt.slice!(0,5)
```

Looks like your `@srt` variable is `nil` i.e. not set to anything. I would bet that it's because of `@array` variable doesn't have fourth element (starting from 0, `@array[3]` returns fourth element).

What you need to do is to use some kind of debugger and hook right into the process. Here's a link to guide about [Debugging Rails Applications](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/debugging_rails_applications.html#debugging-with-the-debugger-gem).

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks! Going to dive into Debugging! But what i dont get, is that it works if i call HousePrice by ID or .last, but not when i run it through the block! So my mistake has to be how i am handleing the block right?

Comment: Probably. Can't say for sure. You need to go through the code, step by step and check what's going on on each stage of the process. Believe me, that's one of the most valuable skills for software engineer to have.

Comment: +1 for introducing me 2 good practice! But it goes into Ruby Source code by step 2 so im still lost! But will keep trying! :)

Comment: You can put several breakpoints to avoid that. Also, as far as I remember there are several ways to go to the next command: one leads you *inside* and other one *right to the next line*.

Comment: Thanks Ninja! Debugging rocks! Should prevent me having to ask stupid questions on here again! :) How come its not covered in more details in some of the books on ruby? Anyway, You did not solve my problem, but you made it so i could, which is so much better! So thank you, and accepting your answer!

Answer (score 0):

Did you already find a solution to your problem?

Concerning the title of your question there seems to be everything correct.

As BroiSatse and marvelousNinja pointed out try to debug the problem in your entire algorithm.

I tried to recreate the problem at hand and in my case the snippet we are talking about works if BroiSatses comment

> Most likely you want pca.postcodes.split...

and marvelousNinjas comment

> I would bet that it's because of @array variable doesn't have fourth
>   element (starting from 0, @array[3] returns fourth element)

are taken care of.

Also this is a great example for practicing best practices, tdd and refactoring.
I used rspec and a PORO(plain old ruby object) just to focus on the posted algorithm.

```
  3 class HousePrice# < ActiveRecord::Base
  4 
  5   attr_accessor :postc, :postcodes
  6   
  7   def initialize
  8     self.postc     = []
  9     self.postcodes = "High Street, Tetsworth, Thame, OX9 OX9 7AB OX9 7AD OX9 7AE OX9 7AS OX9 7AT        OX9 7BS OX9 7BZ"
 10   end
 11   
 12   def self.all
 13     [ HousePrice.new ]
 14   end
 15   
 16   def second_distance_run 
 17     HousePrice.all.each do |pca|
 18       array = pca.postcodes.split(',')
 19       srt   = array[3]
 20       srt.slice!(0,5)
 21       aa    = srt.split(' ')
 22       aa.each_slice(2) do |elem|
 23         postc << (elem[0]) + (elem[1])
 24       end
 25     end
 26   end
 27   
 28 end
 29 
 30 describe HousePrice do
 31 
 32   describe '#postcodes' do
 33     it 'returns a string that includes several postcodes' do
 34       house_price = HousePrice.new
 35       expect(house_price.postcodes).not_to be_nil
 36     end
 37   end
 38   
 39   describe '#second_distance_run' do
 40     it 'sets the postcodes' do
 41       house_price = HousePrice.new
 42       house_price.second_distance_run
 43       expect(house_price.postc).to eq ["OX97AB", "OX97AD", "OX97AE", "OX97AS", "OX97AT", "OX97BS", "OX97BZ"]
 44     end  
 45   end
 46 end
```

Comment: Thankyou for input! The Debugging saved me actually! It was a combination of things, but using pluck helped to for an array from the database. The error was caused because not all of my data was the same, every 200 rows it had "Address/Postcode" which was resulting in the Nil error! Thanks to everyone for there help, and it was Testing and Debugging that saved me, and doubtless will save me again many times in the future! :) I know this is a great example to Refactor, I actually have my Agile book in hand to have a go at it now i have written my tests!